# How to share hard disk with NFS

Tags: nfs, raspbian

I have two machines with raspbian OS.

The first machine has a HD USB connected.

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs       devtmpfs  362M     0  362M   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     367M  5.0M  362M   2% /run
/dev/mmcblk0p2 ext4       29G  852M   27G   4% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     367M     0  367M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     367M     0  367M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1 vfat      240M   23M  217M  10% /boot
/dev/sda2      fuseblk   2.8T  1.3T  1.5T  46% /media/biblio
/dev/sda1      vfat      300M  380K  299M   1% /media/EFI
tmpfs          tmpfs      74M     0   74M   0% /run/user/1000
```

I want to share `/dev/sda2` with the second machine. This is what I did:

Install portman and nfs server in the first machine:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server
$ sudo apt-get install portmap
```

Install nfs client in the second machine:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nfs-common
```

Add a line in `/etc/exports`

```
/media/biblio *(rw)
```

Then, in the second machine I try to show files shared in the first machine:

```
showmount -e 192.168.1.128
```

But I get this error:

```
clnt_create: RPC: Program not registered
```

Why. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `showmount` command is attempting to query the `rpc.mountd` daemon.  Under normal circumstances, it should already be running at this point.

Did you get any error messages when installing nfs-kernel-server?  What happens if you try to start or restart the script manually?

```
pi@nfsserver:~ $ sudo /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server stop
[ ok ] Stopping nfs-kernel-server (via systemctl): nfs-kernel-server.service.
pi@nfsserver:~ $ showmount -e
clnt_create: RPC: Program not registered
pi@nfsserver:~ $ sudo /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server start
[ ok ] Starting nfs-kernel-server (via systemctl): nfs-kernel-server.service.
pi@nfsserver:~ $ showmount -e
Export list for nfsserver:
pi@nfsserver:~ $ ps -ef | grep [m]ountd
root      1599     1  0 20:23 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/rpc.mountd --manage-gids
```

`rpc.mountd` will often log in `/var/log/syslog`.  If it is being started (either manually or by systemd), there should be something there.

When `rpc.mountd` actually starts, it will attempt to register its port with the portmapper.  You can ask the portmapper to show what port it is on.  If it is running, but no port appears, you could have a portmapper issue.

```
pi@nfsserver:~ $ rpcinfo -p | grep mount
    100005    1   udp  40783  mountd
    100005    1   tcp  59249  mountd
    100005    2   udp  56682  mountd
    100005    2   tcp  34875  mountd
    100005    3   udp  49762  mountd
    100005    3   tcp  55881  mountd
```

Finally, if `showmount -e` works on the server, but `showmount -e [host]` doesn't on the client, you could have a networking/firewall issue between them.

Reboot the OSMC server and try adding the following (please edit it into your question, not as comments):

```
ps -ef | grep rpc (on server)
rpcinfo -p (on server)
rpcinfo -p [server] (from the client)
showmount -e [server] (from the client)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I forget to mention that the first machine has OSMC, not raspbian, although is raspbian based. Sorry about that. This is my research based on your guide:

Comment: 1) Restart nfs-kernel-server results in an output exactly as yours, except for exported list: https://pastebin.com/aygPZyi3

Comment: 2) There is no /var/log/syslog file in this machine

Comment: 3) rpcinfo -p | grep mount returns nothing. But rpcinfo -p, without grep filter returns this: https://pastebin.com/xSz0zCgw

Comment: 4) More meaningfull: after restart manually nfs-kernell in the first machine and to do 'showmount -e' in the second machine, I get another error: clnt_create: RPC: Port mapper failure - Unable to receive: errno 0 (Success)

Comment: So, it seems a portmapper issue. How can I fix it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: sda2 seeming to be ntfs, you could just use samba instead of nfs.

Comment: is it not possible to share ntfs filesystem with NFS?

Comment: Not sure what's up.  Default OSMC seems to export with another system just fine with that package.  Suggested some more items for you to add in to the question.

Answer (score 0):

After reinstall Raspbian from scratch in the second machine, everything work. I don't know why.

Thank you all for the help.